# How to change request body in IActionFilter in asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

Currently I am sending encrypted request to asp.net core controller. The following is the request body structure:

```
{
  "body": "pEbXVvl1ue95eGQywK/q80cGHjYk+2VNPYEgnRgU+vI="
}
```

Before that I had implemented the filter `IActionFilter` so in `OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)` where I decrypt the above mention request body(body key)

After decryption, I got the decrypted request body like below:

```
{
  "Urno":"URN123456"
}
```

After decryption, I want to pass decrypted request (mentioned above `"Urno":"URN123456"`) body to controller

I had tried to convert the string to byte than pass it to `Request.body` but no success:

```
public void OnActionExecuting(ActionExecutingContext context)
{
    var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
    request.EnableRewind();
    request.Body.Position = 0;
    using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
    {                   
        var bodyString = reader.ReadToEnd(); //{ "body": "pEbXVvl1ue95eGQywK/q80cGHjYk+2VNPYEgnRgU+vI="}
        if (bodyString != "")
        {
             var data = JObject.Parse(bodyString);
             var key = data.GetValue("body"); 
             var keybytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("808080808080808011");
             var iv = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("8080808080808080111");
             var encrypted = Convert.FromBase64String(key.ToString());
             var decriptedFromJavascript = DecryptStringFromBytes(encrypted, keybytes, iv); //{ "Urno":"URN123456"}
             byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decriptedFromJavascript);
             request.Body = new MemoryStream(bytes); // here i am trying to change request body
        }
    }
}
   // controller
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<string> GetInvestorUrno(Urnoinvestor InfoReq){

}


// class
public class Urnoinvestor 
{
    public string Urno{ get; set; }
}
```

I want to change request body and pass the decrypted request to controller

Comment: What encryption was used on the initial request?  You will need to know that in order to decrypt the information.

Comment: i have decrypted the request now i want to change the request body

Comment: What's the specific problem that you are seeing?  Error Message or Blank page?

Comment: there is no error the  Urnoinvestor InfoReq is null instead of { "Urno":"URN123456"}

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For your scenario, `IActionFilter` would not work. Check this image:

[image]

The `Model binding` is run before `ActionFilter` which means no matter what you changed to the body, it would not change the model. You need to try the filter before Model binding like `Resource filter`.

1. Change to `Resource filter`

   ```
   public class RequestBodyFilter : IResourceFilter
   {
       public void OnResourceExecuted(ResourceExecutedContext context)
       {
           //throw new NotImplementedException();
       }

       public void OnResourceExecuting(ResourceExecutingContext context)
       {
           var request = context.HttpContext.Request;
           request.EnableRewind();
           request.Body.Position = 0;
           using (var reader = new StreamReader(request.Body))
           {
               var decriptedFromJavascript = "{ \"Urno\":\"URN123456\"}"; //{ "Urno":"URN123456"}
               byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decriptedFromJavascript);
               request.Body = new MemoryStream(bytes); // here i am trying to change request body
           }
       }
   }
   ```
2. Since you are binding from body, you need to specify the action with `[FromBody]` as the suggestion from @Tony Abrams.

   ```
   [HttpPost("[action]")]
   [TypeFilter(typeof(RequestBodyFilter))]
   public async Task<string> GetInvestorUrno([FromBody]Urnoinvestor InfoReq)
   {
       return InfoReq.Urno;
   }
   ```

Comment: I'm using the async version in **.Net core 3.1**. Body is not being replaced.
It seems models are bound before.
Anybody trying this?

Comment: @ArminTorkashvand Try an action filter instead. Inherit from `ActionFilterAttribute` and implement `OnActionExecuting`. You can then get the model object via `if (filterContext.ActionArguments.Values.FirstOrDefault(p => p is YourType) is YourType model)`, then just set the property as you normally would. This new value will then appear in the controller.

Answer (score -1):

You don't have the parameter marked as from body, so it's not loading the data from the request body.  Instead it's expecting it in the URI.

Try this instead:

```
[HttpPost("[action]")]
public async Task<string> GetInvestorUrno([FromBody]Urnoinvestor InfoReq){

}
```

Comment: is it correct?                                                                                                                              byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(decriptedFromJavascript);
             request.Body = new MemoryStream(bytes);

Comment: Try System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(decriptedFromJavascript) ... since the other encoding methods use UTF8.

Comment: not working my decriptedFromJavascript is string "{ \"Urno\":\"URN123456\"}" is it what causing the issue ? any my controller accept object